# Training and testing transformer model from scratch

Tags: natural-language, sequence-analysis, machine-translation, transformers

As you know, transformers are one of the strongest model in the field of NLP and machine translation.
I know there are many resources, but I still could not find a good tutorial teaching how to use and train and test transformers on your own dataset (so I also want to obtain the word embeddings using my own algorithms)
If someone has good recommendation, I appreciate to let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want the train the transformer for?

Comment: Mainly, for deep understanding of how the model works and somehow playing with its structure...

Comment: I meant what task and using what data, because this is what the answer depends on.

Comment: How about: 1. https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html
2. https://www.borealisai.com/en/blog/tutorial-14-transformers-i-introduction/ + part 2 and 3 referenced in part 1?